# Ошибка - 0x80070666, при установке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не получается установить python, код ошибки - 0x80070666. Весь питон удалил с виндовс, но возникает ошибка. Буду очень благодарен!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну значит не весь :)

Comment: В сообшении об ошибке есть предложение посмотреть лог установки. Если вы его не посмотрели и не опубликовали, то другим участникам трудно догадатья о его содержимом.